# SQL: OR Statement Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table contains 5 columns: ID, name, email, comment & datetime. I create a search form to let users search records by name or email.

This is my code:

```
<?php

// database info
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$db_name = "test";
$tbl_name = "abctable";

// conntect to server and select database
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("cannot connect server");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("cannot select DB");

// get data from search form
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

// if name & email is not empty, do this
if ((!empty($name)) || (!empty($email))) {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $sql=" SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE name like '%".$name."%' OR email ='".$email."' ";
    $q=mysql_query($sql);
    }
    else{
        $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
        $q=mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
else{
    echo "Please type something in the search box below:<br><br>";
}
?>

<!-- Search Form -->
<form method="post" action="search.php">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Find " /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php 
// Show this Result Table when Search Form is not empty
if ((!empty($name)) || (!empty($email))) { ?>
    <!-- Result Table -->
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Comment</td>
        <td>Date &amp; Time</td>
    </tr>
    <?php while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $res['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['email'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['comment'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['datetime'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
<?php } ?>

<?php mysql_close(); // close database ?>
```

I got problem with the email search SQL. The name is working and successfully return correct record. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You have major problems with SQL generally, like using the old MySQL extension, like not escaping values, like major risk of SQL injection, etc

Comment: I think you want to use the `LIKE` clause for the email, too: `OR email LIKE '%".$email."%'`

Comment: A R G H! Please [read up on mysqli for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and avoid using the [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) standard `mysql`.

Comment: I don't really do PHP, but surely if `!empty($name)` returns false (i.e. `$name` is empty), but `!empty($email)` returns true, you'd end up with `WHERE name LIKE '%%'` in your SQL, which will always match.

Comment: @AndreasBjørn is right, but also have a look at PDO!

Comment: @MarcB it return no result/record.

Comment: Is it possible that `$q` isn't defined outside of the {{}} where you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be an idea to change the query to

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name 
WHERE (".$name." <> '' and name like '%".$name."%')
  OR (".$email." <> '' and email like '%".$email."%')."' ";
```

This will exclude the variable if its empty.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it cleaner do this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{

$sql=" SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE name like $name OR email like $email
$q=mysql_query($sql);

}else
{

echo "Please type something in the search box below:<br><br>";

}
```

I am sure there's a better to doing what you are trying to do. I have a login script, I will check this and post if the above does not work.

Comment: Thanks @ParttimeCoder. I just try it. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I know this is a bit late but did you find the fix for this? If not post us your table creation code, I want to check the finer details. This is the code that you used to create the table.